# How to return to normal display after HDMI disconnect?

Tags: ati, hdmi, output

After I disconnected my TV by pulling the HDMI cable, Ubuntu did not return to the right graphics mode. There is only the background, no launchers or icons, however I can open a menu by right clicking.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, and I have AMD Catalyst 12.10 installed.

Comment: CAPS OFF. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. The result of your question is supposed to stand here as a future reference, should this problem occur to someone again, not only as a answer to you right now.

Answer (score 1):

try switching to a virtual terminal and back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)
This helps when I am disconnecting an external screen.